# Font awesome - change icon inside color on hover

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to change the inside color of an icon when hovering it, I've tried this css code:

```css
.fa-star-o:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<i class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"></i>
```

With this code, only the outline of the icon is changed, not the inside, I want to change the inside color

Answer (score 3):

Use [stacked icons](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#stacked):

```css
.fa-star{
  color: white /* your background color */
}

.fa-stack:hover .fa-star{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6s6p6x04/1)

Comment: And how would I do it if I wanted to use the fa-star with the inside black by default and when I hover it , the inside color turns white?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte [Just change the colors](http://jsfiddle.net/6s6p6x04/2/).

Comment: If you try to do that, It will change only the outline color of the fa-star one , putting it invisible contrasting with the background(white on white)

Comment: @RafaelDuarte I don't understand you - [in the fiddle in my comment](http://jsfiddle.net/6s6p6x04/2/) the `.fa-star` and `.fa-star-o` are black by default and when you hover the elements the `.fa-star` becomes white leaving the `fa-star-o` black. Isn't that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the icon `fa-star-o`. Use only `fa-star`:

```css
.fa-star:hover {
    color: black;
    cursor:pointer
}
.fa-star {
    color:white;
    transition:color 0.5s
}
body {
    background-color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fontawesome.io/assets/css/site.css">

<div style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.5em;" id="parent">
    <div style="font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.5em;">
        <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP only wants to change the inside color of the icon, leaving the _outline_ untouched.